# How do you XOR two list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Say you want to `XOR` two lists

- `list1 = [0,1,0,1]`
- `list2 = [0,1,1,0]`

giving you a new list that is `[0,0,1,1]`.

or maybe `[1,1,0,0]` and `[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]` but only `XOR` on the first 4 then just copy over the rest from the second list into the new one giving you `[0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]`.

Comment: What should happen to [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0] and [1,1,0,0]?

Comment: [0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0] Should come out then

Comment: OK, updated the solution.

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang, you can use recursion to define

```erlang
list_xor([], L) ->
    L;

list_xor(L, []) ->
    L;

list_xor([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) ->
    [H1 bxor H2 | list_xor(T1, T2)].
```

Elixir version:

```elixir
def list_xor([], l),
  do: l

def list_xor(l, []),
  do: l

def list_xor([h1 | t1], [h2 | t2]),
  do: [:erlang.bxor(h1, h2) | list_xor(t1, t2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Oneliner, just out of curiosity.

```rb
[Stream.concat([1,1,0,0], Stream.cycle([nil])), [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0]]
|> Enum.zip()
|> Enum.map(fn {nil, e} -> e; {e1, e2} -> :erlang.bxor(e1, e2) end)
#⇒ [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```elixir
import Bitwise

def xor(list_1, list_2), do: do_xor(list_1, list_2, [])
defp do_xor([], [], results), do: Enum.reverse(results)
defp do_xor([element_1 | tail_1], [], results), do: do_xor(tail_1, [], [element_1 | results])
defp do_xor([], [element_2 | tail_2], results), do: do_xor([], tail_2, [element_2 | results])
defp do_xor([element_1 | tail_1], [element_2 | tail_2], results), do: do_xor(tail_1, tail_2, [element_1 ^^^ element_2 | results])
```

What we are doing here is using pattern matching to check if one of the lists is an empty list - if it is, just append the current `element` (head) from the other list to the `results` list.

If both lists contain elements, use `Bitwise.^^^/2` to do an XOR comparison.

Finally, if both lists are empty (`[]`), reverse the `results` list and return it.

P.S. Notice how we are prepending to the FRONT of the results list and not appending to the back (this would be done like `new_results = results ++ [element]`) because the list data structure in Elixir is set up in such a way that prepending to the front is much faster (`O(1)`) than appending to the back (`O(N)`).
Since we are appending to the front of the `results` list, the results are in the reversed order. This is why we do `Enum.reverse/1` in the final step, to put the results back in the original order.

Comment: Nice use of tail recursion. I did a quick benchmark, and the performance seems roughly same as the non-tail-recursive version (at least for the small lists I tested with). The non-tail-recursive version is also simpler, as it builds up the result in the call stack, removing the need for the `results` variable and additional function clauses, so I'd probably go with that.

Comment: The problem with the non-tail-recursive version (@choroba's answer) is not the lack of performance but that it will create a memory leak in large enough lists.
Every time a function is called, the Erlang VM adds a stack frame and some memory is allocated. Now imagine a list with A LOT of elements. Without tail recursion, it will keep allocating more and more memory and your application will crash.
Since the Erlang VM implements tail-call optimization, it basically re-uses the same frame when calling a function recursively and not allocating new memory.

Comment: That is [erlang myth #1](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/myths.html#myth--tail-recursive-functions-are-much-faster-----than-recursive-functions) :-)

Comment: Really cool resource! I haven't read this one before, thanks!

My point here still stands - I am NOT talking about the SPEED at which the functions execute, but about the memory allocation. If we have a predetermined list size and we know we have enough memory then either is fine, but if the input can be a list of size N, without tail recursion, we are in danger.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you store the list in an accumulator or on the call stack - it's probably going to use the same amount of memory. But adding a list reverse makes the tail-recursive version potentially worse. This is discussed in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

If you `use Bitwise` to get the [`^^^`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Bitwise.html#%5E%5E%5E/2) operator, you can do this simply with a combination for a [comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) and [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2):

```elixir
use Bitwise
for {x, y} <- Enum.zip([0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0]), do: x ^^^ y
```

Output:

```elixir
[0, 0, 1, 1]
```

---

For lists with different lengths, @choroba's recursive example (upvoted) is great. Here's a version of that, using the `^^^` operator:

```elixir
use Bitwise

defmodule Example do
  def list_xor([], l), do: l
  def list_xor(l, []), do: l
  def list_xor([h1 | t1], [h2 | t2]), do: [h1 ^^^ h2 | list_xor(t1, t2)]
end
```